# How to parse a Carbon AppleEvent using Cocoa (NSAppleEventDescriptor?)

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

In the process of modernizing a carbon app, I'd like to rewrite the handing of AppleEvents in Cocoa, especially because I find the Carbon AEFunctions quite ugly.

I found NSAppleEventDescriptor but I'm confused about how to create one from an AppleEvent* in order to easier access its elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `AppleEvent` is an `AERecord` is an `AEDescList` is an `AEDesc`. So, you can create an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` using `-initWithAEDescNoCopy:`.

That said, if you're writing Apple Event handlers in Cocoa, then you should register them with `-[NSAppleEventManager setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:]`. Your handler method would then receive an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` as a parameter and you wouldn't have to worry about constructing one from an `AppleEvent`.